# Bad Archive in IOS

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, archive

I want to **distribute** my App in the **Ad Hoc mode**. I have archived more than 50 times and it always worked like i want.

When i **compile my App on the phone everything running as well**. i get all last modification on the storyboard.

The problem is that when **i try to archive now my App**, the archive **compile an old version** of my app. I don't know how to resolve that.

Have you got any idea ?

Comment: clean and rebuild your app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i clean in Product -> clean and rebluid in Product Build and nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps

Confirming it builds and runs correctly in the simulator and when building directly to an iPhone. Everything works great in these cases.

Cleaning the project.

In the Organizer, deleting all archives and removing the project.

Manually deleting the DerivedData folder.

Renaming the IPA and updating the distribution plist to ensure that the file isn't somehow being cached on the web server.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I check my playlist and the problem was there. I was trying to download my app from local where my **.plist** link ipa to the web server. That why i download an old version.